# How do i find if the model is new or has no property in it : backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This is my backbone model and collection:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model :  myModel,
});
```

when i do `new` of model

```
debitRow = new myModel();
```

this will have no property or value in it.

now how do i find that the model is `empty or not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made it to work like the following,

```
if(_.isEmpty(debitRow.attributes)){
                        // do your stuff
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did You try with .isNew() , documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew)

Comment: `isNew()` only checks the `id` property.

Comment: @fbynite - Thanks, I didn't aware of that